# iPython - "broken" shell/terminal after realoading Django

Tags: django, ipython

I'm embedding iPython shell in a Django script (with development server, e.g. runserver at localhost) like this:

```
...
from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
ipshell = IPShellEmbed()
ipshell()
...
```

which gives me interactive shell at the desired place. Now, if modify the source code, Django automatically reloads, probably without correctly quitting iPython shell, and "breaks" my terminal emulator (xterm, konsole) - text becomes invisible, etc. (same effect if iPython running inside Django is terminated with Ctrl+d).

Any suggestions as what could be causing this? (I'm probably using iPython in a wrong way, but who knows).

Comment: I've been having the exact same problem with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace`, so it probably isn't an iPython-specific issue. However, I have only noticed this happenning when using a virtualenv (with virtualenvwrapper), so perhaps that's what's causing it.

Comment: Got the same problem, would love the anwser. +1

Comment: Not just virtualenv. It happens for me running default python in Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot answer the question why it's going wrong, but I can tell you how to recover from it: quit the debugging server and give the `reset` command.

Another way to prevent this from happening is to use the `--reload` switch on the `runserver` command. This means that Django will not reload after a change, but it also doesn't break your debugger.

Comment: Thanks! 'reset' also works around the problem with 'import pdb; pdb.set_trace()' noted by Aram Dulyan above.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already fixed: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15565

Thanks Django.